# Error in creating SQlite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am creating a table with three columns . Here is the Dasebase.java class ::

```
    package digicare.phonebook;

    import android.R;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View.OnCreateContextMenuListener;

    public class Database {


private static final String DATABSE_NAME ="MY_DB";
private static final String DATABSE_TABLE ="MY_TABLE";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;


public static final String KEY_ID = "ID" ;
public static final String  PHONE_NUM ="NUMBER";
public static final String PERSON_NAME="NAME";

public static final String DATABASE_CREATE =" CREATE TABLE " + DATABSE_TABLE + " (" + 
                                             KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                                             PHONE_NUM + " TEXT NOT NULL, "+ 
                                             PERSON_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL)" ;


private DatabaseHelper myHelper;

private final Context mycontext;
private SQLiteDatabase myDB;


private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABSE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ DATABSE_TABLE );
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public Database(Context c){
    mycontext=c;
}
public Database open() throws SQLException {

    myHelper=new DatabaseHelper(mycontext);
    myDB= myHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this ;
    }
public void close(){
    myHelper.close();
}
public long createEntry(String number, String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues() ;
    cv.put(PERSON_NAME, name);
    cv.put(PHONE_NUM,number);
    return myDB.insert(DATABSE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
    }
```

From other class i call the createEntry() method to insert a row in database but LogCat gives the error : that " No such table: MY_TABLE "

through the piece of code i call the createEntry method :

```
    btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String number =edtxt_num.getText().toString();
            String name =edtxt_name.getText().toString();
            //number and name
            Boolean diditwork=true;
            try{
            Database entry = new Database(enter_data.this);
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(number , name);

            entry.close();
            }catch(Exception e ){
                Log.w("error", e.getMessage());
                diditwork=false;
            }finally{
                if (diditwork){
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
                    d.setTitle("Ring Manager");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext()) ;
                    tv.setText("Saved");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();

                }
            }


        }
    });
```

Can i have to create the table first ???? by calling the onCreate(db) method ???? or it automatically created when i insert a new row ????

Comment: The table is created 1st whenever you call getWriteable/getReadable database.

Answer (score 0):

`DatabaseHelper.onCreate()` is only called if the database doesn't exist yet. If you made prior tests and created a database without the table it won't be created later.

Possible solutions:

- Delete the database (should be in directory "/data/data/<app package name>/databases")
- Increment `DATABASE_VERSION`

Comment: No, there is not any folder like this  "data/data//databases"

Comment: @user2569548 There was an error in the first version of my answer, sorry. The directory is at "/data/data/<app package name>/databases" where you must replace "<app package name>" accordingly. Accessing the directory may need using ADB directly or a rooted device.

Comment: @user2569548 you will find it under the file Explorer. if you are using emulator and eclipse. goto windows open perspective ddms file explorer

Comment: @MichaelButscher i find the database in (data/data/digicare.phonebook/databases/MY_DB)

Comment: @user2569548 Because `onCreate()` is meant to create the initial structure of the database. If the database exists already the database helper thinks that a call to `onCreate()` isn't necessary anymore (it doesn't check the presence of a particular table).

Comment: @user2569548 Could you delete the database file (should be done while your app isn't running)?

Comment: remove database file at `data/data/digicare.phonebook/databases/MY_DB` and run your app.database will create again.

Comment: to remove db file you can use adb shell or go to app settings in settings menu and clear your application data.